# Why do template functions default to float instead of double in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, types

Preface: I know I can do this with overloading, or by using multiple typenames in the template. I am just trying to learn how templates work and would like to understand what I'm seeing.

Please consider this template, which intentionally assumes all args are the same type just to provide an example:

```
template <typename T>
inline T saturate(T val, T lower, T upper)
{
  T val1 = val > lower ? val : lower;
  T val2 = val1 < upper ? val1 : upper;
  return val2;
}

int main()
{
   double v = 1.234;
   saturate(v, 0.0, 90.0);
   return 0;
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'saturate(double&, float, float)'
```

As there is no suffix to explicitly declare those literals as doubles, it is my understanding that C++ should just default them to type double:

> The type of a floating literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify float, the suffixes l and L specify long double.

So why does the compiler treat them as floats by default?

Again, **I know I can fix this many different ways**. I just want to understand the error!

Thanks.

Update: Had not considered that this might be a compiler-specific issue. I am building using `arm-none-eabi-g++ -std=c++14 -std=gnu++14`

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. I get all as `double` https://godbolt.org/z/3feavEs68

Comment: How about a [mcve] so we can see what you're seeing?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do template functions default to float instead of double in C++?

Template arguments don't implicitly default to anything. Either you provide a default, specify the argument explicitly, or the template argument is deduced from the function arguments.

In your example program, the `T` will be deduced as `double`.

> This generates the following error:
>
> ```
> no matching function for call to 'saturate(double&, float, float)'
> ```

It does not: https://godbolt.org/z/4sr5E6xzv

---

P.S. Avoid the unnecessary use of macros. Use variables instead in order to benefit from the type system and scoping.

Comment: I added details of the compiler I'm using which does indeed produce that error. Had not considered it might be specific to the compiler. P.S. the macros are there to avoid using externs, not that it is in any way relevant to the question I was asking.